# Internal language of a topos: what can we say about $0$, $1$, $\Omega$ ...?

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, topos-theory

I am trying to understand how the internal language of a topos works, but there are few examples in the various sources I read and in particular I found no examples related directly to specific objects of the topos, like the terminal object $1$ or the subobject classifier $\Omega$. For example, are the following judgements valid in every topos?

$$ x : 1, y : 1 \vdash x = y\tag{1} $$

$$ \vdash \exists w : \Omega, w = w\tag{2}$$

$$ x : 0 \vdash \bot \tag{3}$$

Comment: What sources are you referring to?

Comment: The three I use the most at the moment are [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.5647.pdf), [MacLane & Moerdijk](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/SMIM.pdf) and [de Moor](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3427/PRG98.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. Use `[text](link)` for the link `link` with text `text`.

Comment: I would recommend chapter 3 of John Bell, Toposes and local set theories, for explicit proofs in the internal language.

Comment: (1), (2), and (3) are valid in every topos.

Comment: (2) even has a formal proof in the language from more basic rules/axioms: since $\vdash \top = \top$, using ${\exists}I$ it follows that $\vdash \exists w : \Omega, w = w$.